# Problema para listar dados do banco

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com problemas para armazenar os valores do `ORDER BY` em php, gostaria de armazená-los em um array e mostrá-lo em outra página.

Arquivo do banco de dados com a função:

```
    function buscar_rank($conexao) {
    $sqlBusca = 'SELECT * FROM usuario ORBER BY pontos;';
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sqlBusca);

    $usuarios = array();

    while ($rank = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        $usuarios[] = $rank;
    }

    return $usuarios;
}
```

arquivo onde gostaria de armazenar os resultados

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <?php $lista_rank = buscar_rank($conexao); 

       foreach($lista_rank as $rank) :
       ?>
       <td><?php echo $rank['nome']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $rank['pontos']; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Qual o problema? Retorna algum erro?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\back\banco.php on line 69  a linha 69 contem o escopo do while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `ORDER` esta escrito errado, troque para:

```
$sqlBusca = 'SELECT * FROM usuario ORDER BY pontos;';
```

Você também pode melhorar sua função alterando para:

```
function buscar_rank($conexao) {
    $sqlBusca = 'SELECT * FROM usuario ORDER BY pontos;';
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sqlBusca);

    return mysqli_fetch_all($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

A função `mysqli_fetch_all` já retorna todas as linhas em formato de `array` associativo.

Comment: Retorna o seguinte erro: mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: Alterei a resposta, na verdade `ORDER` estava escrito como `ORBER` e estava dando erro na `query`.

Comment: Deu certinho. Muito obrigado e desculpa a falta de atenção...

Comment: Se deu certo dê um `upvote` na respota e marque-a como solução do problema.